# text alignment drawInRect Not Working

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, drawrect

I have the following code which draw text in a UITableViewCell, it's working fine for drawing and return the text but in the Center of UITableViewCell. So I gave it Right Alignment but not working!!

```
UIColor * textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
if (self.selected || self.highlighted){
    textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
}
else
{
    [[UIColor whiteColor] set];
    UIRectFill(self.bounds);
}

[textColor set];

UIFont * textFont = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];

CGSize textSize = [text sizeWithFont:textFont constrainedToSize:rect.size];

[text drawInRect:CGRectMake((rect.size.width / 2) - (textSize.width / 2),
                            (rect.size.height / 2) - (textSize.height / 2),
                            textSize.width, 
                            textSize.height) 
        withFont:textFont 
   lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap 
       alignment:UITextAlignmentRight];
```

Comment: You should be using `NSLineBreakByWordWrapping` and `NSTextAlignmentRight` as the UI equivalents have been deprecated. They map to the same thing so it shouldn't make a difference though.

Comment: "not working" For the Alignment.
I used the UI equivalents (NSLineBreakByWordWrapping and NSTextAlignmentRight) but still not working!! the text still in the Center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check the `CGRect` you passed to `drawInRect:`? You're explicitly creating a `CGRect` in the center of `rect`. It should be:

```
[text drawInRect:CGRectMake(rect.origin.x,
                            (rect.size.height / 2) - (textSize.height / 2),
                            rect.size.width, textSize.height) 
        withFont:textFont 
   lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap 
       alignment:UITextAlignmentRight];
```